# Trying to compile the Paho MQTT C example on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, makefile, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am trying to run the Paho MQTT example in C on my raspberry pi: https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/

I tried just downloading the pre-built binaries and linking to `lpaho-mqtt3c`

I put that library here: `/home/pi/mqtt_C_testing/Eclipse-Paho-MQTT-C-1.3.1-Linux/lib`

And I added:  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/mqtt_C_testing/Eclipse-Paho-MQTT-C-1.3.1-Linux/lib/`

My makefile looks like this:

```
IDIR = /home/pi/mqtt_C_testing/Eclipse-Paho-MQTT-C-1.3.1-Linux/include
LDIR = /home/pi/mqtt_C_testing/Eclipse-Paho-MQTT-C-1.3.1-Linux/lib
CC = gcc
LD = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
LIBS = -lpaho-mqtt3c

PROG_NAME = main

# directories in project
BIN = bin
SRC = src
OBJ = obj
INCLUDE = include

INCLUDES = -I./$(INCLUDE)

all : $(PROG_NAME)

$(PROG_NAME) : $(BIN)/$$@

$(BIN)/% : $(OBJ)/%.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(BIN)/main : $(addprefix $(OBJ)/, \
        main.o)

$(OBJ)/main.o : $(addprefix $(INCLUDE)/, \
        MQTTProperties.h MQTTReasonCodes.h MQTTSubscribeOpts.h MQTTClient.h \
        MQTTClientPersistence.h MQTTAsync.h)

$(OBJ)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.c
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o
```

When I try to build though, gcc cannot find the library:

```
gcc -Wall obj/main.o -o bin/main -lpaho-mqtt3c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpaho-mqtt3c
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:26: bin/main] Error 1
```

My directory structure is like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mqtt_C_testing $ ls
bin  Eclipse-Paho-MQTT-C-1.3.1-Linux  include  makefile  obj  src
```

And I have main.c (the mqtt example file) in `src` and I put all the MQTT header files in `include`.
The library files for mqtt are here:  `/home/pi/mqtt_C_testing/Eclipse-Paho-MQTT-C-1.3.1-Linux/lib`

I'm really not sure if I'm the right track at all here, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used during load time (ie, when the program is run) and not during build/link time. Use `LDFLAGS=-L$(LDIR)`

Comment: @kaylum I still get the same error if I put LDFLAGS=-L$(LDIR) in my makefile.  I also tried putting the .so file in /usr/local/lib but then I get the error:  `//usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized`  I am not sure why it has the double slash and if that is a problem?

Comment: Does the `gcc` command change after `LDFLAGS` change? Regarding, "file format not recognized" it looks to me like the prebuilt binaries are for x86 and my understanding is that raspberry pi is arm. So you may need to build the lib yourself.

Comment: Oh I missed something - I thought you were using an implicit rule for the `main` binary but you have an explicit rule. So you need to add `$(LDFLAGS)` to the command for the `$(BIN)/%` rule. But you probably still need to rebuild the lib to be arm binaries.

Comment: I built the lib by cloning the repo at https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c and ran `make` then `make install`.  I can now at least compile from the terminal.  With all the MQTT*.h files and main.c in the same folder I run `gcc -Wall -o test main.c -lpaho-mqtt3c` and it actually compiles.   The biggest difference though is that libpaho-mqtt3c.so is now in /usr/local/lib.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to compile I did the following:

1)  I built the lib by cloning the repo at github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c and ran `make` then `make install`.  This puts the .so files in /usr/local/lib

2)  I put all the .h files in the main folder of my project directory: `/home/pi/mqtt_C_testing/`

3)  I called the paho mqtt synchronous example `main.c` and have that also in the main directory.

4)  I can then simply use:  `gcc -Wall -o test main.c -lpaho-mqtt3c` to build and create an executable called "test"

5)  I had success writing a makefile also that is run just with `make`.  I'm a noob to all this, but I found this website (http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) really helped with creating the makefile. I have not really had success putting the .h files in their own include directory yet though.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = MQTTAsync.h MQTTClientPersistence.h MQTTProperties.h MQTTClient.h MQTTReasonCodes.h MQTTSub$
OBJ = main.o
LIBS= -lpaho-mqtt3c


%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

mainmake: main.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```